# update query in sqlite not showing me error

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-delete

I tried to `update` a row which doesn't exits in order to get an error but it shows nothing ; same thing is happening with `delete`.

```
sqlite> select * from student;
2|Abhi|79
3|Jatin|95
sqlite> update student set name = "xyz" where rno = 7;
sqlite> delete from student where rno = 7;
sqlite>
```

Comment: It is not an error.  Your expectation is wrong.

Comment: where is it stated that you should get an error?

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. Instead post the code/errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) to see what other information you should provide. There's also a tool there for making plain text representations of tables.

Answer (score 3):

Attempting to modify (update or delete) a row that does not exist is not an *error*. The query is valid SQL, which is properly parsed and executed by the database. No row matches the condition defined in the `where` clause, so no row is affected (updated or deleted).

On the other hand, errors are raised:

- at parse time, ie when the query cannot be compiled, for example because its syntax is invalid, or if it references a table or column that does not exists in the database
- during runtime if something unexpected happens, like a division by zero, a scalar subquery returning multiple rows, and so on